# sshd file ownership changing from root user to asterisk

Tags: linux, sshd

Is there any possibility that manager API can change the file ownership of sshd_config file from root to asterisk user?

I'm trying to control the asterisk Using Java code via manager API. 
I can able to access asterisk but the problem is after restarting the machine the sshd_config file ownership is changed from root to asterisk. Even If I change the ownership back to root manually, it changing back to asterisk at every restart.

Comment: What manager API are you talking about?

Comment: Asterisk Manager Interface API. Using this I can able connect from my host OS to Asterisk Instance via ssh.